# improve calling next method in JAVA

Tags: java

I'm looking for a better way to organize my class.
Right now my code looks like this:
mainMethod:
-number1 input
-call method1 with number1 als value

method1:
-do "stuff" with input
-call method2 with new "stuff" as value

method2:
-do stuff
-call method3

etc...

So i start with user input in my main method and my whole class works like domino, the first method needs to be called to run the next method.
I would rather have method1 return a value and save it in some global variable in my class which can be used by method2 and so on.
Here is my Code with exactly this problem: (it calculates sqrt)

```
package wurzel;
import java.util.Scanner;
import wurzel.Fraction;

public class wurzel {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
                Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
                System.out.println("Eingabe:");
                int in = s.nextInt();
                s.close();
                bisection(in);
        }
        private static int bisection(int N){
                int counter = 0;
                for(int i = 0; i < N;i++){
                        if((counter*counter) > N){
                                counter--;
                                break;
                        }
                        else if(counter*counter == N){
                                break;
                        }
                        else counter++;
                }
                calculateSequence(counter,N);
                return counter;         
        }

        static int[] calculateSequence(int vKomma, int look){
                int m = 0;
                int d = 1;
                int a = vKomma;
                int[] intarr = new int[4];
                intarr[0] = vKomma;
                for(int i = 1; i <= intarr.length; i++){
                        if(i == intarr.length )
                                break;
                        else{
                                m = (d*a) - m;
                                d = (look - (m*m)) / d;
                                a = (vKomma + m) / d;
                                intarr[i] = a;
                        }
                }
                calculateApproximation(intarr);
                return intarr;
        }

        static double calculateApproximation(int[] sequence ){
            Fraction result = new Fraction((sequence.length)-1);
            for(int dcounter = sequence.length; dcounter > 0; dcounter--){
                result = result.reciprocal().add(sequence[dcounter-1]);
            }
            System.out.println("Approximation als double: " +result.doubleValue());
            System.out.println("Approximation als Bruch: " +result);
            return result.doubleValue();            
        }      
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should also seperate code into different classes. E.g. have a generic MathHelper class which has these methods in it.

This helps keep code seperate and easy to read.

Comment: Thats what i wanted to do, too. Unfortunately, the task is to find a solution with only one class.

Comment: Ahh. Well I guess as long as you comment the code well and keep the code well formatted, you should be ok. I agree with Peter though, it's not unusual... It's not clean, but it's not unusual.

Answer (score 0):

You mentioned that you wanted to store some data in a global variable for the class as a whole. The way to do this is by making the class use instance methods rather than class methods. With class methods, you have to use class variables. But, when you use instance methods, you can define instance variables which can be accessed by any method within the class.

To do this, change all your methods (apart from main()) by removing the keyword `static` from each method. Then, define the instance variable that is global for the class. e.g. if your global variable is of type int then it would be:

```
private int myInstanceVariable;
```

This instance variable, or global variable, can be accessed by a getter and setter.

Comment: I'm not sure if I'm allowed to change "static".But I guess I will try it. Thanks

Comment: What he means is that your static method would not be able to access those instance variables ("global" in your terms) if you leave your methods as static. So turn your methods into instance methods.

Comment: You can remove static. However, in your main(), you must instantiate an instance of wurzel. e.g: wurzel wz = new wurzel(); Then pass the instance methods to the reference, e.g.   wz.bisection(5);

Answer (score 0):

It is quite normal methods to call each other and to form long chains of calls.
So I would not worry about that. Actually in real world, in enterprise code,
you have call stack going through tens of calls. So I think global variables would 
be worse practice compared to what you did.

Comment: The problem is, I have to add another input which isn't used in method1 or method2. So i have to add another paramenter to these method which has no use there and is only used in the last step.